# js import via building the string

Tags: javascript, import, importerror

To my understanding javascript `import` statements imports from a string. So building a string and importing should work

```js
let myLib = "foo";
import * as app from `./${myLib}.js`;
```

this however doesn't work

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing module specifier after 'from' keyword
```

---

I have the following directory structure:

```
main.js
lib/
  myLib0.js
  myLib1.js
  ...
```

each `myLibN.js` contains a function named `bar` and I want to import just one `myLibN.js` use it inside `main.js`.

What is the proper way to solve this?

Comment: I would give the modules meaningful names and import them independently.

Comment: no. One and **only one** of the `myLibN.js` is imported basted on parameters. I tried to simplify the problem. Edit: Edited question to clarify.

Comment: Then probably [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#description).

Comment: Thanks @Andy !  I didn't know the name. If you can post this as an answer I can mark as solved